# css image doesn't appear when I zip, send and unizip my project

Tags: html

I'm doing a simple project on Visual Studio Code and when I open the pages in live server, the images load correctly, but when I zip the files, send to another person and unzip the file, que imgs doesn't load.
The rest of the CSS works Ok, the only problem is the images.
The code runs perfectly on live server @ VSCODE

Comment: I guess it's related to the path of the images. Are you using relative paths like `../../images/kitten.png`  or absolute ones like `project/assets/images/kitten.png`?

Comment: Caio, this is not a good question. I'm happy you've solved your problem, but please, next time, include things that will help others solve your problem such as the minimum required HTML and CSS code for this project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

solved.. i missed the two dots before the path

../imgs/image.jpg

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, I'm glad you've solved your issue, but for helping to future developers that might encounter this issue, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation